# css, match menu top

Tags: html, css, menu, hover

I wonder if is possible to do this by pure css.

Please check my example http://jsfiddle.net/fantill/72xjU/1/

Now when I hover the menu, the sub menu will show up right next to the hovered menu.

I want to set, all sub menu's top to match 2 level menu's top.

```
--------------------------------------------------
|                                                |
|                                                |
--------------------------------------------------
|         |              |  <- 2nd one is selecting
|/////////|              |  <- top match 1st sub menu top
|         |              |  
----------|              |
          |              |
          |              |
          ----------------
```

Thank you very much for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that complicated. In fact, you just have to remove the position relative from the list elements of the submenu. The [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VLBv9/) ist here:

```
.MM ul ul li {
   position:static;
}
```